# wp8: gif picture is not animating in the app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have `loading.gif` file in my app. if i used jpg picture, it was shown in the app. if i used gif picture, animation is not shown. [it was been like jpg pic]

Markup:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">  
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="browser" IsScriptEnabled="True" Margin="-12,0,-11,0" LoadCompleted="htmlLoadCompleted"/>         
<Image x:Name="CoverImage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Assets/loading.gif" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>  
</Grid>
```

Code :

```
private void htmlLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.CoverImage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Comment: I am confused, you are telling the image control to collapse - so it would not be seen???

Comment: http://wp.qmatteoq.com/how-to-display-gif-images-in-a-windows-phone-application/

Comment: image is displayed. but not animated. @DonA

Comment: @ChrisW. went thru the url already u have mentioned, but still confused

Comment: ok check the solution..

Comment: Looks like @tanuj_loop got you sorted out. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install the imagetools from nuget package manager ..
and add this namespace to your xaml..

```
xmlns:imagetools="clr-namespace:ImageTools.Controls;assembly=ImageTools.Controls"
```

then add this to your page resources..

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <imagetools:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

then define image in xaml like this..

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <imagetools:AnimatedImage x:Name="CoverImage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding ImageSource, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
```

now do this in your code behind..

```
private Uri _ImageSource;
    public Uri ImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            return _ImageSource;
        }
        set
        {
            _ImageSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ImageSource");
        }
    }

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ImageTools.IO.Decoders.AddDecoder<GifDecoder>();
        ImageSource = new Uri("/Assets/loading.gif", UriKind.Relative);
        this.DataContext = this;
        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }
```

it is better if you imeplement InotifyPropertyChanged in your page.cs like this..
add this to you code..

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(String str)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventArgs e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(str);
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
```

and inherit your class from InotifyPropertychanged..like this..

```
 MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage,INotifyPropertyChanged
```

hope this helps you..